# Flutter BLoC variables best practice

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Started recently using the BLoC approach for building apps, and one thing that is not clear is where to "keep" BLoC variables. I guess we can have these two options:

1. Declare a variable in the BLoC class; for example in my class I can do the following:

```
class ModulesBloc extends Bloc<ModulesEvent, ModulesState> {
   late String myString;
}
```

And access it in my UI as follows:

```
BlocProvider.of<ModulesBloc>(context).myString;
```

2. Keep it as a state variable; for example I can declare my state class as follows:

```
class ModulesState extends Equatable {
   const ModulesState({required this.myString});

   final String myString;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [myString];
}
```

And access it in my UI as follows:

```
BlocBuilder<ModulesBloc, ModulesState>(
   builder: (BuildContext context, ModulesState modulesState) {
      modulesState.myString;
   }
)
```

Are there any performance penalties / state stability issues with any of the above approaches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure there is an absolute answer but I can at least give my opinion.

In bloc you have 3 objects: `bloc`, `event`, `state`.

The `state` is the mutable part while the `bloc` is a description of the your problem (what `state`s to emit for each `event`). As such, an **immutable** variable to describe your problem should be, in my opinion, placed inside the `bloc`. However, anything which might change is the `state` of your bloc (same as the `state` of your widget) and should as such be stored in the `state`.

**Example:**

You want to create an app where you can set timers. In this app you can have multiple timers, each of which will be identified by a `name`.

In this case:

- your state will be an object containing a double variable called `timeCount`, which will be incremented each seconds for example.
- You bloc will have a `final` field called `name` which will have to be set during the creation of the stopwatch.

Interestingly enough, if you want the bloc to also handle the stopwatch *creation*, you will have 2 states: the first empty, the second with a `name` and `timeCount`. See how naturally `name` became variable and is therefore found in the `state` now.

Comment: Thanks Lulupointu for the nice example! So eventually, it is about "interpreting" which variables are mutable and which ones not..

Comment: Well it's not much of an interpretation, you always know which are which ^^ But if you meant determining yes that's the case.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. So as a final thought, in my case where I have a list of modules that gets updated (item added, removed, etc), I will initialize it in the BLoC class, and use the state to reflect changes to it. But another concern of mine was about performance. If there are hints on this, it would also be great!

Comment: I don't think performance matters here. All of this are basic operations which are really fast and in the worst case asynchronous so they should not cause any jank. Concerning your case, I think you do it the right way but you should NOT have a variable referencing to your list in your bloc, you should only use it to instantiate your initial state (in `super`). Unless you need a reference to this list at a latter point, in which case this could be debatable, I think I would still keep it in the state anyway but as I said it's more a matter of concistancy and personal preference